# How to fix 'Cannot marshal 'return value': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (Int/UInt must be paired with SysInt or SysUInt).'

Tags: c#, c++, struct, pinvoke, dllimport

I'm trying to return a struct from a C++ callback from C# and I get the error as described in the title.

I appreciate there is a lot of information, but I wanted to include too much rather than not enough.

I've tried returning the function as a structure, but then read it may be easier to return the function as an IntPtr and use Marshal.PtrtoStructure.

The function that I want to call is from a .dll that comes from a different source and the input is:

C++:

```cpp
rVDACQ_Connect(int, tVDACQ_CallBackProc, void*, short*, int)
```

the function in the sample (C++) code returns a struct (rACQ_CallBackRec) which is as follows:

```cpp
rACQ_CallBackRec = theApp.m_Intf.rVDACQ_Connect(cVDACQ_FBright, CALLBACK_Acquisition, this, m_FrmBuffer, 0);
//rACQ_CallBackRec is the struct type tVDACQ_CallBackRec (as described below)
```

With CALLBACK_Aquisition being:

```cpp
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) void _stdcall CALLBACK_Acquisition(tVDACQ_CallBackRec* AR)
    {
        tVDACQ_CallBackProc test;
        ((CPreviewDlg*)AR->rUserParam)->My_ACQ_CallBack(AR, test);
    }
}
```

The layout of the struct is as follows:

```
typedef struct {
    int    rFlags,            // combination of cVDACQ_Fxxxx
        rType,             // cVDACQ_ETxxx
        rEvent,            // cVDACQ_Exxx
        rSocket;           // 0:no relation to a 'socket'; otherwise socket's ID>0 (event's source ID) 
    TCHAR  rMsg[256];         // message (trace, wrn, err)
    int    rFrameWidth,       // full frame width
        rFrameHeight;      // full frame height
    short* rFrameBuffer;      // user supplied frame buffer "AFrameBuffer"
    union {
        int    rCaptureRows;      // # of received rows (for single frame acquisition)
        int    rCaptureFrames;    // # of received full frames (for framegrabber)
    };
    int    rCapturePercent;   // received data in percents
    void* rUserCallBackProc, // user supplied "ACallBackProc"
        * rUserParam;        // user supplied "AUserParam"
    int    rAborted;          // 1: VDACQ_Abort -1:internally
    void* rPacketData;       // pointer to received packet; usually it is nil  
    int    rFGControl;        // frame-grabber's control flags
} tVDACQ_CallBackRec;

typedef void(_stdcall* tVDACQ_CallBackProc)(tVDACQ_CallBackRec*); //The Callback
```

C#

I've created the callback procedure in C#, as well as the struct and PInvoke:

```cs
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public delegate void tVDACQ_CallBackProc(tVDACQ_CallBackRec AR);

[DllImport("C:\\Users\\jch\\source\\repos\\FlatPanelSensor\\x64\\Debug\\VADAV_AcqS.dll", EntryPoint = "CALLBACK_Acquisition", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public unsafe static extern void CALLBACK_Acquisition(tVDACQ_CallBackRec AR);

[DllImport("C:\\Users\\jch\\source\\repos\\FlatPanelSensor\\FlatPanelSensor\\bin\\Debug\\VADAV_FGM_64.dll", EntryPoint = "VDACQ_Connect", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
        public unsafe static extern IntPtr VDACQ_Connect(int i, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] tVDACQ_CallBackProc proc, dynamic n, IntPtr[] buffer, int j);
```

Struct:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct tVDACQ_CallBackRec
        {
            public int rFlags;
            public int rType;
            public int rEvent;
            public int rSocket;

            [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 256)]
            public string rMsg;            

            public int rFrameWidth;
            public int rFrameHeight;

            public IntPtr rFrameBuffer;

            public int rCaptureRows;
            public int rCaptureFrames;
            public int rCapturePercent;

            public IntPtr rUserCallBackProc;
            public IntPtr rUserParam;

            public int rAborted;

            public IntPtr rPacketData;

            public int rFGControl;
        }
```

CallBack:

```
tVDACQ_CallBackProc callBack =
                (AR) =>
                {
                    CALLBACK_Acquisition(AR); //Don't know how necessary this 
                                                is
                };
```

Function call:

```
IntPtr work = VDACQ_Connect(0, callBack, this, m_FrmBuffer, 0);
//I know 'this' isn't defined as a void* in my DLLImport,
//but making it an IntPtr didn't work either so 
//the only type I could think of was dynamic.
```

If I could return this as a IntPtr or, even better, the struct I defined in my C# code that would be great.

If you need anymore information then please let me know, as I think I included everything.

Comment: Is `rVDACQ_Connect` the same as `VDACQ_Connect`? What's its return type (you missed that out of its C++ signature)

Comment: In the sample code rVDACQ_Connect is just what they defined the function as when loading in the library and the return type is the struct tVDACQ_CallBackRec which I also included as part of the C++ code. Hope that helps let me know if you need anything else or if I missed anything else.

Comment: So if it returns a tVDACQ_CallBackRec, why does your P/Invoke signature have it returning an `IntPtr`?

Comment: Because I read somewhere (can't remember where) that I could return as a IntPtr and then use Marshal.PtrToStructure. I have, however, tried returning as tVDACQ_CallBackRec and IntPtr. When I use tVDACQ_CallBackRec as the return type I get 'Method's type signature is not P/Invoke compatible' which I assume is something wrong with the struct

Comment: Returning an `IntPtr` would only work if the C++ function returned a pointer to something. However the C++ function is returning something *by value*: it's not returning a pointer. When you tried returning tVDACQ_CallBackRec, did you remove the `MarshalAs` attribute from the return value?

Comment: Yes when I return tVDACQ_CallBackRec there is no MarshalAs, as it is only used in the function parameters for the callback as ```[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)] tVDACQ_CallBackProc proc```

Comment: Lots of issues. TCHAR could be ansi or unicode, make a choice in C#. tVDACQ_CallBackRec AR parameter should be marked as `ref`. You should remove `[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]` from VDACQ_Connect to be consistent with IntPtr. You shouldn't need `unsafe`. Don't use FunctionPtr at all. Change `dynamic n` by `IntPtr n`. `IntPtr[] buffer` may be ok but it depends what C expects and what you pass to it.